# Get ORM config name from EnityManager object in EntityListener

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

Hi i'm working on preupdate function like

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args){
    $em = $args->getEntityManager();
}
```

> I would like to know if it's possible to get the config name of the entity
>   manager with $em object (Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)

In my config.yml

```
orm:
    ...
    entity_managers:
        connection1:
            ...
        connection2:
            ...
```

I try to get string "connection1" or "connection2"

Thanks :)

Comment: The Doctrine entity manager knows nothing about the Symfony configuration system.